# preg_replace() tags name

Tags: php, css, regex, laravel, preg-replace

I have CSS file with many tags, some strings:

```
p{
    margin:10px 0;
    padding:0;
}
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{
    display:block;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

I trying get this:

```
#content p{
        margin:10px 0;
        padding:0;
    }

#content h1,
#content h2,
#content h3,
#content h4,
#content h5,
#content h6{
        display:block;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }
```

I try find like this: `([^\n|,{]*\n+)` but get body of tags, but not name of tag.
How I think - I need to find `}` and `\n` or `,`

Answer (score 0):

[preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) is your friend:

```
$css = <<<EOD
p{
    margin:10px 0;
    padding:0;
}
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{
    display:block;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
EOD;

$result = preg_replace_callback(
    '/\n?([\w,\h]+)(?=\{)/',
    function ($m) {
        $l = preg_replace('/\w+\h*,?/', "#content $0\n",$m[0]);
        return $l;
    },
    $css
);
echo $result;
```

**Output:**

```
#content p
{
    margin:10px 0;
    padding:0;
}
#content h1,
#content h2,
#content h3,
#content h4,
#content h5,
#content h6
{
    display:block;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

**Explanation:**

```
\n?         : optional linefeed
(           : start group 1
  [\w,\h]+  : 1 or more word character or horizontal space
)           : end group
(?=\{)      : positive lookahead, make sure we have a curly brace after
```

Second regex:

```
\w+         : 1 or more word character
\h*         : 0 or more horizontal space
,?          : optional comma
```